# mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.ImageGrid : invert_yaxis not working

Tags: matplotlib

How can I invert the Y axes in an ImageGrid plot grid?

This is my current test code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import ImageGrid
import numpy as np

im1 = np.arange(100).reshape((10, 10))
im2 = im1.T
im3 = np.flipud(im1)
im4 = np.fliplr(im2)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4., 4.))
grid = ImageGrid(fig, 111,  # similar to subplot(111)
                 nrows_ncols=(2, 2),  # creates 2x2 grid of axes
                 axes_pad=0.1,  # pad between axes in inch.
                 )

for ax, im in zip(grid, [im1, im2, im3, im4]):
    # Iterating over the grid returns the Axes.
    # ax.imshow(im)
    ax.pcolormesh(im)
    ax.invert_yaxis() # This seems to have no effect.

plt.show()
```

ax.invert_yaxis() has no effect and I always get increasing Y values like in this picture:

[image: ImageGrid]

Comment: I would guess this is something to do with `QuadMesh` not being a regular Axes? Also adding `print(ax.yaxis.get_inverted())` to the loop prints `True, False,True, False`

Comment: Yes, it toggles the Y axis instead of setting its direction. I figured it out eventually. They should add a link to set_inverted in the documentation for invert_yaxis.

Comment: Hmm, but if you uncomment `ax.imshow(im)` then it _does_ work, no?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the problem was that [ax.invert_yaxis()](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.invert_yaxis.html) toggles the Y axis direction instead of just setting it.
Since I looped an even number of times, it had no effect.

Here are two possible solutions:

1. Use `ax.yaxis.set_inverted(True)`. Cf: [set_inverted](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axis.Axis.set_inverted.html)
2. Invert the Y axis only for one plot in each row:

   ```
   if idx in [0,2]:
     ax.invert_yaxis()
   idx+=1
   ```

Working example code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import ImageGrid
import numpy as np

im1 = np.arange(100).reshape((10, 10))
im2 = im1.T
im3 = np.flipud(im1)
im4 = np.fliplr(im2)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4., 4.))
grid = ImageGrid(fig, 111,  # similar to subplot(111)
                 nrows_ncols=(2, 2),  # creates 2x2 grid of axes
                 axes_pad=0.1,  # pad between axes in inch.
                 )

idx=0
for ax, im in zip(grid, [im1, im2, im3, im4]):
    # Iterating over the grid returns the Axes.
    # ax.imshow(im)
    ax.pcolormesh(im)
    # ax.invert_yaxis()
    
    # Directly setting the axis direction, rather than toggling it.
    ax.yaxis.set_inverted(True)
    
    # Alternative method:
    # if idx in [0,2]:
    #   ax.invert_yaxis()
    # idx+=1
    
plt.show()
```

[image]